# Eclipse Indigo Crashes Very Unstable

Tags: eclipse

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with JRE 8.  I am a newbie tying to learn javascript, but I have the rather annoying problem that my Eclipse Indigo SR2 x86_64 installation crashes every few moments.

Solutions I've tried:

1. Purging / reinstalling Java (sometimes after a crash I get an error message stating that Java crashed, but most times Eclipse simply crashes and no message.)
2. reinstalling Eclipse
3. Adding " -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mo­zilla " at the end of the eclipse.ini file  (no change in crashing behavior)
4. Checked for updates

My error log says the following:

> !SESSION 2015-11-06 16:15:11.677
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800 java.version=1.8.0_66
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=linux,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_HK Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.javascript.product Command-line arguments: 
>   -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.javascript.product
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2015-11-06 16:15:40.366 !MESSAGE Ignored
>   reentrant call while viewer is busy. This is only logged once per
>   viewer instance, but similar calls will still be ignored. !STACK 0
>   java.lang.RuntimeException    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.checkBusy(ColumnViewer.java:763)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.update(ColumnViewer.java:552)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchContentProvider$4.run(WorkbenchContentProvider.java:334)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchContentProvider.runUpdates(WorkbenchContentProvider.java:159)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchContentProvider.processDelta(WorkbenchContentProvider.java:132)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchContentProvider.resourceChanged(WorkbenchContentProvider.java:106)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:395)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1530).......

Greatly appreciate any tips for getting Eclipse to work properly.

thanks,
yup

Comment: Indigo is ancient, how about using the current version (Mars).

Comment: well as stated, newbie... there seems to be a plethora of eclipse versions available I am looking for the version specifically for javascript, not php or java as my machine is not very heavy weight.. a referral link would be appreciated.